# How to check if ios package `ipa` has crypt?

Tags: ios, crypt

How to check ios app has crypt?

not `otool`

I mean using `objective-c` or `c` codes in app to check ipa has crypt and do different logic?

For example: if user installed a crypted ipa, popup a error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "a crypted ipa"?  Which ipa?

Comment: I mean a ipa after clutch. Sorry my english is poor.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in github:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/6a8d436f0943f10220fddb81b89e27c23ac72e2f/Firebase/Core/third_party/FIRAppEnvironmentUtil.m

In this class, has method `+ (BOOL)isFromAppStore;` `static BOOL isAppEncrypted()`